# Stop CVS export -r from including removed files

Tags: export, cvs

I've recently started using CVS for personal projects and I'm running into a problem with exporting by a tag. I commit all changes, but only tag files for production (PRD) when ready. I use
`cvs export -rPRD module_name`
and this works well, except I realized that when I `cvs remove filename` and commit, it is still included in subsequent exports.

How do I stop the export from including removed files? Is there a different way, like somehow specifying a tag and a revision, that might do this correctly? I have tried `cvs export -Dnow -rPRD module_name`, but this always exports nothing.

Comment: I seriously don't mean to be rude, but "recently" and "CVS" shouldn't be seen in the same sentence. Not in the 21st century, at least. Haven't you considered using something sane like `git` instead?

Comment: @dawud This is a fair question. I had experience with SVN at school, and we use CVS at work (R/D is planning a transition to git now, I believe). So, it just fit with my experience to use it on my own site.  I'm not against git, it's just that cvs fit with my system: single developer, single machine.

Comment: I agree it's a fair question., but even for a single developer in a single machine (or precisely because of that), there's little to no point in running a SCM from the past.